# Travel with an Italian residence permit

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, aegean-airlines

I am an Egyptian citizen. I have a family residence permit for Italy for five years. I want to book a flight from Egypt to Rome Transit in Athens. I want to make sure if the Italian residence permit allows me to travel through Greek airlines.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your EU residence permit (whether as a family member of an EU citizen or not) allows you to travel to other Schengen states for 90 days out of every 180 days. You do not need a visa or any other special permissions for this itinerary.

Comment: I would add that the same is true of any residence permit issued by any Schengen country.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica no.  To travel to another *Schengen* country, within the 90/180 rule, *any Schengen residence permit* will do.  To travel to a *non-Schengen* EU country without a visa (or, technically, to exceed the 90/180 rule in Schengen) it must be a family member residence card and the traveler must be accompanied by (or joining) the family member.  Otherwise, a Nigerian living in Geneva would have to get a visa to go shopping in France.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. I'll delete my erroneous comment.